# How do I set a conditional controller view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I have a default view for my main controller set on routes.rb. When a new user comes I need the controller to use a different view. Something like this:

```
def set_view
  if @new_user
    render 'tutorial'
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

I just can´t make it work. Any insight here would be great.

Comment: What error are you seeing? More context on exactly where you're running into trouble might be helpful here

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one 'render' called in your action. 
Just keep the view name in variable and feed it to 'render' at the end.

```
view = @new_user ? 'tutorial' : 'index'
render view
```

Comment: You can only *make* one render call.  The original code snippit would only execute one call.